# How to fix "lateinit property YYY has not been initialized"

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, obd-ii, kotlin-lateinit

I have a class that makes bluetooth connection and gets a PID from an OBD bluetooth dongle that its connected in the car.
But when calling the method for getting RPM then I have an Exception about not initialazing that property.

```
class BluetoothOBDManager : OBDManager {
    lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var input: InputStream
    private lateinit var output: OutputStream
    private lateinit var rpmCommand: RPMCommand
    private lateinit var coolantTempCommand: EngineCoolantTemperatureCommand
    private lateinit var airIntakeTempCommand: AirIntakeTemperatureCommand
    private lateinit var mmSocket : BluetoothSocket

    fun connect(deviceString: String) {
        var adapter: BluetoothAdapter = getDefaultAdapter()
        val device = adapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceString)
        val uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB")
        val mmSocket:BluetoothSocket=device.createRf....Record(uuid)

        mmSocket.let { socket ->
                socket.connect()
            }

        input = mmSocket.inputStream
        output = mmSocket.outputStream
        if (mmSocket.isConnected) {
            println("output.write =1")
            output.write(1)
        }
        rpmCommand = RPMCommand() //This is the INIT of the propert
    }

    override fun getCurrentRpm(): Int {
        rpmCommand.run(input, output) // This line throughs the EXCEPTION
        return rpmCommand.rpm
    }
}
```

**This is how I call the method from another class**

```
BluetoothOBDManager().connect(deviceString)
            var rpm  = BluetoothOBDManager().getCurrentRpm()
            rpmTextView.setText(rpm)
```

**The exception**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: gr.obd.logger, PID: 17486
    kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property rpmCommand has not been initialized
```

**I have tried to INIT the property inside the method but no luck**

```
  override fun getCurrentRpm(): Int {
        rpmCommand = RPMCommand()
        rpmCommand.run(input, output) // This line throughs the EXCEPTION
        return rpmCommand.rpm
    }
```

Comment: You didn't initialized `coolantTempCommand` this

Comment: sorry copied the wrong Call. I use getCurrentRpm() and I have a lateinit not initialised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BluetoothOBDManager().connect(deviceString)
        var rpm  = BluetoothOBDManager().getCurrentRpm()
```

Your code creates a `BluetoothOBDManager`, connects it (initializing `rpmCommand`), then throws it away, creates a *new* `BluetoothOBDManager` with everything uninitialized and tries to call `getCurrentRpm` on it. It likely should be

```
val obdManager = BluetoothOBDManager()
obdManager.connect(deviceString)
val rpm = obdManager.getCurrentRpm()
```

This doesn't explain why you would get

> I have tried to INIT the property inside the method but no luck

but that *really* shouldn't happen; I expect something else is going wrong.

Comment: sorry copied the wrong Call. I use getCurrentRpm() and I have a lateinit not initialised . I have edited my first post.

Comment: See the edit. As a side note, I'd reconsider relying on `lateinit` so much in the first place.

Comment: that was it! Wrong call of the method.